# Wordpress background-image in :after

Tags: html, css, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields, custom-fields

How do i make a custom field for a background-image, which is in :after selector?
The problem is that i have to make it changebale

```
<div id="pr1" class="project-slide>
    <span class="project-title"><?php echo $project_title2;?></span>
    <p><?php echo $project_text2;?></p>
</div>


  div#pr0.project-slide:after{
    background-image: url(http://localhost/ruby/wp-content/uploads/2017/05/720_500_specialnij.png);
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
<div id="pr1" class="project-slide>
    <span class="project-title"><?php echo $project_title2;?></span>
    <p><?php echo $project_text2;?></p>
</div>




div#pr1.project-slide:after{    
    content:url(http://localhost/ruby/wp-content/uploads/2017/05/720_500_specialnij.png);
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this might work out for you if not it should be something along these lines.

```
 <?php
 $your_field = get_field('your_field');
 ?>

 <style>
 div#pr0.project-slide:after{
     background-image: url(<?php echo $your_field['url']; ?>);
 }
 </style>
```